# listview Onitemclick listener in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, onitemclicklistener

I am getting trouble on itemclick listener in android using Sqlite ,i am getting the data from sqlite data base and i need to pass the same arraylist to next activity using onitemclick listener.,But its not working .

```
 contactList.clear();


          String query = "SELECT  * FROM MessageTable  WHERE userID = '" + userid +"'"; 

          System.out.println("queryinsert="+query);

          Cursor c1 = sqlHandler.selectQuery(query);
          if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
           if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
             ContactListItems contactListItems = new ContactListItems();

             contactListItems.setSlno(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("ID")));
                         contactListItems.setmessage(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("message")));

             contactList.add(contactListItems);

            } while (c1.moveToNext());
           }
          }
          c1.close();
         }
```

here is the arraylist   `ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList`where i am storing the sqlite data , i need to pass the data to next on eachitem click ,could anybody guide me .@Thanks

Comment: Use bundle to share the values.

Comment: but the problem is i can't click the listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this one. You can pass ArrayList of class using Serializable interface. check below code.

```
1) you have to implement Serializable interface in your ContactListItems class like 

public class ContactListItems implements Serializable {

}

2) Pass arraylist of ContactListItems via intent:

Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ContactListData", arrayListData); //  here arrayListData is the object of ArrayList<ContactListItems>
startActivity(intent);

3) get Intent of ArrayList containing ContactListItems class:

ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactListData;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras != null) {
    contactListData = (ArrayList<ContactListItems>) extras
                    .getSerializable("ContactListData");

   }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: error!!05-21 16:39:52.335: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.universal.ContactListItems@4a21a958

Comment: let me search for this exception. Try Parcelable interface instead of Serializable and also changed intent while getting extras like: contactListData = (ArrayList<ContactListItems>) extras.getParcelable("ContactListData");
check this link for more information: http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

Comment: This is for Serializable object error.
it can't fully marshal ContactListItems, maybe you're not implementing it properly or have something that can't be marshalled? check you have implementing "import java.io.Serializable;" package properly...

Comment: Thanks for your help ..i have implemented everything how could i get the particular list details

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30331/discussion-between-maulik-and-priya2134412)

Answer (score 0):

overide onitem click listener for ListView http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

you can use bundle and also you can use another class which have ArrayList contactList variable and in listview click retrive id of row and pass that id using bundle and there you go

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill your entity class with your Cursor you should use a for statement,now your are getting just the first row in your Cursor and reinstantiate your class

```
for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) 
{
}
```

and for your list listener use :

```
YourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
    }});
```

**Edit** : this is the code how you put an arraylist to the intent

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Tets",YourArrayList);
```

Comment: if you put this listener after setting your list adapter it shuold be clicked , otherwise put the related code (listview layout or listview definition) maybe someone can help

Comment: ok..now its working but how could i pass ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList to next activity

Comment: define a Bundle then in your listener fill your Bundle and send it with your Intent

Comment: can i pass Arraylist of class using bundle

Comment: thanks but still it show error The method putStringArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<String>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<ContactListItems>)

Comment: ContactListItems in your code is your class entity?am i write? so first you should define an arraylist then in forloop fill your Array with your entity then put it in your Intent.

Comment: yes..ContactListItems is the class entity ,i tried not working

Comment: @priya2134412 I would like to suggest you atleast upvote the answer who are very enthusiastically trying to solve your question.